# Setting app.helpMenu is not displaying the help menu

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a MacOS app that is written in Swift. It uses Cocoa and not SwiftUI. I want to setup a custom help menu. I don't have any help files and associated setting in Info.plist. This custom menu will have a link to a webpage and another action to show a list of navigation keys. I tried

```swift
app.helpMenu = helpMenu
```

where `helpMenu` contains the two actions. When I run the app, I don't see "Help" menu. I only see the rest of the mainMenu. Since it is a custom help anyway, I could just pretend it to be part of the mainMenu. But I am considering using the standard helpMenu feature as I may have help files bundled with the app in the future. How do I get it to work?

Comment: The regular Help menu should be set up already - if this is a completely new menu, how are you creating and adding it to the main menu?

Comment: The app is not from any template and is completely built from scratch. So, I use NSMenu, NSMenuItem to build the mainMenu and also helpMenu.

Comment: If you are just setting it as NSApp's helpMenu, you also need to add it to the main menu like any other.

Comment: Yes adding it to mainMenu worked. But whether or not helpMenu is set made no difference at that point. So, it is unclear what special powers helpMenu provides.

Comment: The special powers are described in the documentation.

Comment: Setting NSApp's helpMenu just tells the system to recognize it as the actual help menu, not just a menu named "Help", so you get extras such as the Spotlight menu item.  NSApp's windowsMenu works the same way.

Comment: Thanks @red_menace, since I had the menu named "Help" I found no difference. Changing the name to something else showed the difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @red_menace mentioned, in addition to setting app.helpMenu, it also needs to be added to the app.mainMenu.

Comment: This answer would be far more useful if you showed the complete solution. Your current answer is lacking any useful details.